# how can I find the number of an item in an array in android studio?

Tags: java, android, arrays

Does anybody know how to find the number of an int inside an array? So, I want to find if `studentID` (is an int) inside `studentArray` in enumeration. The array `studentArray` consists of other arrays. AND it should return as an array (student1 and student2 is an array) as I'm going to need the array for further development.

Tried other codes but they don't seem to work or I just don’t know how to implement them properly.

```
public int studentID;
private Context sContext;

int[] sImageID = {0};

class_ViewPager(Context context, int studentID) {
    sContext = context;
    studentID = studentID;
}

private  int[] student1 = new int[]{ R.drawable.test1, R.drawable.test2 };
private  int[] student2 = new int[]{ R.drawable.boboy5, R.drawable.boboy4 };

private int[][] studentArray = new int[][]{
        student1,
        student2
};

if(studentID == studentArray){
    sImageID = studentArray; // i know this code is wrong but i want the retun value to be sImageID(array too) for further development.
} else {}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return sImageID.length;
}
```

Example: let's say `studentId` is 2 then it should return `student2`, which is number 2 from the array.

Comment: `studentID` can not equals `studentArray`. to get a student from array you can do something like studentArray[0] (will return the student at index 0)

Comment: im sorry sir, but how can I implement that to my code? sorry for being a noob

Comment: currently, the data for a student is `student1 = new int[]{ R.drawable.test1, R.drawable.test2 }`. So what is the id of student? `R.drawable.test1` or `R.drawable.test2 `

Comment: student id is passed from the main activity which is an integer (1,2,3 and so on...) which i have set to be global in here (this activity is a class from the main activity)

Comment: I understand. So if student id also is student index in array, you can get a student by `studentArray[studentID]` like `int[] student = studentArray[studentId];`

Comment: i think yes? im also wondering how to do a for loop for finding that studentID inside studentArray.

Comment: thinking about why you need for loop in this case?

Comment: yeah I know man. sorry, this is just a one time project for my friend. i dont have much time to learn java.Thank you for your time.

Comment: no problem, if you learn like this, first I think you need to learn about debugging and log, then try to debug every line in your code and see how the code running. Then you can both see how code running and what is the result. And when problem happened, you may know which place cause it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to retrieve the contents of the studentArray based on the value of studentID, then you can create a method inside the class like:

```
int[] getStudent() {
   return studentArray[studentID-1];
}
```

Java arrays are zero-based. That's the reason for studentID-1 above.